# Lyx Convertors for Lilypond to pdf

Tags: lyx, lilypond

I want to include Lilypond snippets in my report, but I'm getting an error:

> An error occurred while running pdflatex "project_name.lytex"

I believe I don't have the convertor set up correctly in

> Tools -> Preferences -> File Handling->Convertors.

Originally, it was complaining about convertors, so I added Lilypond book (LaTeX) -> Latex (pdflatex), using convert-ly as the convertor. And now I'm getting the error.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You should not have to add any convertors yourself. On Ubuntu, LyX + lilypond works out of the box for me (i.e. no custom configuration at all). Which OS are you using? Try doing a fresh reconfigure (note that this will delete your preferences and shortcuts and convertors so we will copy the folder before deleting): exit LyX, rename your home folder (~/.lyx* on Linux), and start LyX. Then try compiling the Lilypond example that comes with LyX (File > Open > Examples lilypond.lyx). Does it work? If not, LyX probably did not find lilypond so it might be a PATH issue.

Comment: Thanks, Ive done that, and when running the example, I'm getting the error missing prerequisites lilypond-book->latex.
Im running Lyx on windows. everything else in Lyx seems to be running fine. its just the inclusion of Lilypond that seems to be an issue

Comment: Then there is probably a PATH problem. We often see this from Windows users for some reason that I don't understand. Go to Tools > Preferences > Paths and add the location of the lilypond binary in the PATH prefix.

Answer (score 1):

`Lilypond-book` processes a `.lytex` file that contains both Lilypond code and LaTeX code. It separates the Lilypond code and turns it into PDFs, and then creates a `tex` file which includes commands to insert the PDFs into the LaTeX document at the appropriate places.
Finally, it uses LaTeX to render the `tex` file into a PDF with both music images and text.

`Convert-ly` is *only* used to update `lilypond` syntax from older version. It should not be needed in your situation.

The normal command-line chain of commands for processing a `lilypond-book` document is this:

```
lilypond-book --pdf file.lytex
pdflatex file.tex % or other engine like lualatex
```

Someone else will have to advise whether Lyx can be set up to do this. A minimal example would be helpful.

See the Lilypond documentation at http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/invoking-lilypond_002dbook